# Solving a simple integral by derivating w.r.t. to constants

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

In the following [notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/separation.pdf) on the solution of the Wave equation by Separation of Variables, in Example 2 the following derivation is given
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^1 x \sin(k\pi x) d x
   & = \int_0^1 -\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{d}{d k} \cos(k\pi x) d x \\
   & = -\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{d}{d k} \int_0^1 \cos(k\pi x) d x \\
   & = -\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{d}{d k} \frac{1}{k\pi}\sin(k\pi x) \Big \vert_0^1 \\
   & = -\cos(k \pi) \frac{1}{k \pi}
\end{align*}
I do not understand it, what he means by differentiating by $k$? In my understanding $k$ is a constant, and of course I can solve this integral easily with integration by parts and using that $\cos(k\pi) = (-1)^k$, but I am asking what he has in mind, to me it does not make sense to derivate w.r.t. $k$?

Comment: would it help to think of $k$ as a **parameter** rather than as a constant?

Comment: Yes, today I see it, it is simply $\frac{d}{dk} \cos(k\pi x) = \pi x \sin(k\pi x)$, and then using $\frac{d}{dk} \sin(k\pi)/k = (k\pi\cos(k\pi) - \sin(k\pi))/k^2$, and then he uses $k \in \mathbb Z$ so that $\sin(k\pi) = 0$, I was too commited to think in integration by parts, but this has nothing to do with this technique :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is really meant here is:
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^1 x \sin(k\pi x) d x
   & = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial k}  \left[
(k,x)\to -\frac{1}{\pi} \cos(k\pi x)\right] (k,x) d x \\
   & \color{red} =  \frac{d}{d k} \left[ k\to  \int_0^1 -\frac{1}{\pi}
 \cos(k\pi x) d x\right] (k) \\
   & = \frac{d}{d k} \left[k\to -\frac{1}{\pi^2 k} \sin(k\pi) \right] (k) \\
   & = -\cos(k \pi) \frac{1}{k \pi}
\end{align*}

The key equality is in red. This is true for every $k\neq 0$, not only for integers.

Answer (score 1):

> *In my understanding, k is a constant.*

No! A specific value of *k* is a constant. However, *k* itself is a [*parameter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter#Mathematical_functions). It is not “bound”

to a single specific value. $I(k)=\displaystyle\int_a^bf_k(x)~dx$ is a function of argument *k*. As is also

$S(k)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=a}^bt_k(n),~$ or $~P(k)=\displaystyle\prod_{n=a}^bu_k(n).~$ Of course, in order to differentiate something,

one must first prove that the function in question is differentiable in the first place $($with

regard to *k*, **not** the iterator *x* or *n* $)$.